# How to use resources for rackPick in anylogic?

Tags: storage, anylogic, warehouse

I am using anylogic to simulate a warehouse.

I use `rackstore` and `rackpick` to store and pick the items from the pallet-rack.
When I use resources to pick the items, the Error

`Exception during discrete event execution: root.retrieval.attach: The agent is not in a network`

occurs.

There is no problem during storing the items using a resource.

Do you have any idea, how I can fix this?

[rackPick-Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRwv8.jpg)

Comment: on the contrary, the problem occurs probably when you store the items. The key is in the block that comes after the rackstore block. You may be accidentally taking the item outside the network...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After the racksore block, I have a Wait block. In this Block I did not choose "Agent Location", because Palletrack is not available as location there. So what should I choose as "agent location"?